# Bookmarklet: run JS command after page is loaded

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser, automation

I build quite a lot of bookmarklets to automate my every day's work. Now I faced a problem: I would like (by clicking on a bookmarklet) to open a page in web browser and apply some specific operation on its interface. The web application is old and does not provide some advanced option like table filtering. I have this functionality already written, now I would like to open a web app and apply my JS code by one click on bookmarklet.

So I would like 3 steps to by done by one click:

> **1. Open some webpage.**
>
> **2. Wait for webpage to be fully loaded.**
>
> **3. Run some JS command, let say alert('test');**

I tried few times, but it seems impossible to me.

So I would like to be sure: is it do-able?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probbaly want to use Greasemonkey (FF) or tampermonkey (Chrome)

Comment: @epascarello - Unfortunately, I don't have enough privileges on my workstation to install extensions. That's why I am asking about bookmarklet.
Thanks anyway for you tip!